# regex rules in jupyter

Tags: python, regex, jupyter-notebook

Are they regex rules in python jupyter different? 
for example, i can not use [] in jupyter. I got an error.

Comment: Hi Ariane. Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you add a little more detail - specifically, are you using a code window or a markdown window within Jupyter when you attempt to use Regex? Also, can you tell us whether you're attempting to use regex through a python library like *re*

Comment: Thank you. I am new in programming with python with regex. I use a markdown window. and i use also re library. but most of the things that i learn from regex in python are not work in jupyter.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That might be the issue - if you're using Python (or any code other than HTML) in a markdown window, the markdown language won't process it correctly. Check that you see a pair of brackets [ ] surrounds a cell number, that tells you you're using code.

Comment: @Ariane can you give us a concrete example of piece of regex code that works in the terminal but not in jupyter?  We can't help you unless we can reproduce the behavior you are experiencing.  Help us to recreate your exact experience.

Comment: @MisterJT Is "my code doesn't work in Jupyter" --- "You're using a markdown window" a common jupyter-related question?

Answer (score 1):

[image: The below shows a code cell and a markdown cell in Jupyter.]

Please confirm you're using regex within the code cell.